# Installing gcc 4.8 on 13.10 “The following packages have unmet dependencies”

Tags: gcc, binutils, ubuntu-13.10

When I go to install gcc 4.8 using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
```

I get the error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
gcc-4.8 : Depends: binutils (>= 2.23.90.20131017) but 2.23.52.20130913-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I've binutils at the newest version. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection,
go to software center->edit->sources->choose best server.